# Xcode Debugger logging weird exceptions from within objc-exception.m

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, exception

Since updating to Xcode 8 and macOS 10.12 I'm getting logs in the debugger console, which are so excessive that the whole computer slows down to unbearable speed.

I set a breakpoint in main.m on the very first line in my application and start the debugger. Even before hitting this breakpoint, I get these logs:

`objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: *** Setting default (non-Foundation) exception mechanism
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: entered try block 0xbfffc290
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: removing try block handler 0xbfffc290
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: entered try block 0xbfffc340
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: removing try block handler 0xbfffc340
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: entered try block 0xbfffc3f0
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: removing try block handler 0xbfffc3f0
objc[18986]: EXCEPTIONS: entered try block 0xbfffc4a0`

These are massive (several hundreds) even before the breakpoint is hit. I looked them up, and google tells me, that those can be found in `objc-exception.m`. The problem is that there is an apparent `PrintExceptions` boolean, but it is never set anywhere - and it seems to be true for my special case, as this only happens with that one project. I didn't change anything in the project settings.

How do i get rid of those logs?

Answer (score 1):

`OBJC_PRINT_EXCEPTIONS` was set in your `Run` scheme.

It might not be visible in the Scheme editor UI (Xcode bug?). Just manually edit the scheme file to get rid of it.